# Hubot/Express: disable basic auth in a specific route

Tags: node.js, express, basic-authentication, hubot

I am using Hubot and I've defined the environment variables EXPRESS_USER and EXPRESS_PASSWORD to enable basic authentication. Hubot uses express and basically it's

```
setupExpress: ->
    user    = process.env.EXPRESS_USER
    pass    = process.env.EXPRESS_PASSWORD
    stat    = process.env.EXPRESS_STATIC

    express = require 'express'

    app = express()

    app.use (req, res, next) =>
      res.setHeader "X-Powered-By", "hubot/#{@name}"
      next()

    app.use express.basicAuth user, pass if user and pass
    app.use express.query()
    app.use express.bodyParser()
    app.use express.static stat if stat`
```

I want to expose an HTTP command in a script that doesn't need basic auth. However I'm not able to change change the code in Hubot where express it's being initialized

```
robot.router.get '/some-anonymous-path', (req, res) ->
  console.log 'Should be here without need to authenticate
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to do it in expressjs.

Thanks in advance

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

How about putting nginx in front of your Hubot? Then you can also add SSL, only allow access to specific paths, rewrite urls or even serve static content created by hubot scripts. A simple example nginx.conf block:

```
upstream hubot {
  server localhost:8080;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  satisfy any;
  allow 127.0.0.1;
  deny all;
  location ~ ^/(public|obscured) {
    allow all;
    proxy_pass http://hubot;
  }
  location ~ ^/(static) {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
    root /www;
  }
  location ~ {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
    proxy_pass http://hubot;
  }
}
```

Then toss an htpasswd pair in /etc/nginx/htpasswd and in your hubot init script set `BIND_ADDRESS=localhost` (default bind is 0.0.0.0) and you'll be off to the races.