# install custom middleware into hubot's express

Tags: express, hubot

Is there a way to install my own custom middleware into the express object provided by hubot?

I wanted to use code like this, but I never see the messages "Added middleware" or "Initializing express". I was using code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392180/hubot-express-disable-basic-auth-in-a-specific-route) as a model.

Can I override [setupExpress](https://github.com/Taytay/hubot/blob/19d0e1d1e4b30d1ed2e1bf2d411a57809c29a3a1/src/robot.coffee) somehow? Or, is there a way to subclass Robot to do this?

```
    # Setup our own express handler                                                                                                                                                        
    express = require 'express'
    robot.express = app = express()
    app.use require 'body-parser'

    app.use (req, res, next) ->
            robot.logger.info "Added middleware"
            req.rawData = ''
            req.on 'data', (chunk) ->
                    req.rawData += chunk

            req.on 'end', () ->
                    next()


    robot.logger.info "Setting up new express module"

    robot.emit 'express-loaded', @
    @loaded = true

    @init = (port, bindAddress) =>
            robot.logger.info "Initializing express"
            unless @initialized
                    try
                            @server = app.listen( port || process.env.PORT || 8080, bindAddress || process.env.BIND_ADDRESS || '0.0.0.0' )
                            @router = app
                            @initialized = true
                    catch err
                            robot.logger.error "Error trying to load"
                            process.exit 1
            @
```

Comment: I filed a bug (https://github.com/github/hubot/issues/923) on this one.